# Can't access env variables in RUN script.sh Dockerfile

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have this Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

# ENV VARIABLES
ENV INI_FOLDER /usr/local/etc/php
ENV WWW_FOLDER /var/www

# ADD THE ENV CONFIGURATOR AND SET PERMISSIONS
ADD env.sh $WWW_FOLDER/
RUN chmod +x $WWW_FOLDER/env.sh

RUN /var/www/env.sh
```

The problems is that in `env.sh` I don't have access to the variables set on the docker-compose. Is there any workaround to fix this?

UPDATE: added docker-compose

```
version: '2.0'

services:
  app:
    env_file:
      - app/mysql.env
      - app/app.env
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\svirl\Documents\workspace\docker\my-app:/var/www/html/:rw
    build: app
```

Comment: `env.sh` should have access to `$INI_FOLDER` and `$WWW_FOLDER` when it's run.  What exactly is making you think it doesn't?

Comment: You mention docker-compose. Can you add your compose file as well?

Comment: Hi, I added your requests. I am not referring to $INI_FOLDER, I did not tested those vars, I am referring to `app.env` and `mysql.env` vars.